# React Native Splash Screen Issue - after modifying xml files in android folder

Tags: java, android, xml, reactjs, react-native

I would like to create a splash screen in my React Native app (not Expo) using Android Studio's emulator.

I was trying to add a splash_screen.xml file into android/app/src/main/res/drawable folder. When I put a  new .xml file into the android folder the React compiler shows the following error message:

iMac:newtest Dora$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/Dora/Documents/code/react native/newtest/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/Dora/Documents/code/react native/newtest/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/Users/Dora/Documents/code/react native/newtest/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

Thank you for taking your time to help me to solve this issue!

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Maybe if you try to update the version of Android SDK Build Tools  it'll fix the issue, I do it in the console of Android Studio when it builds

Answer (score 4):

Well, finally I have managed to solve this issue. It is for those who will encounter this problem during Android development.

So, what i did exactly: 
1. cd into android folder and run this: ./gradlew installDebug
After this command finished without any errors

2. go back to the root directory and start the app using: react-native run-android

Conclusion, if you add or change any xml files in android folder, you have to do the above procedure.

That's all!

Alex